# Como puedo hacer que el programa entregue los valores del array aleatoriamente un cierto numero de veces?

Tags: array, c, random

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char hebra_original[81] = {'A', 'G', 'T', 'C'};   
    return 0;
}
```

Mi pregunta es la siguiente: cómo puedo hacer que los valores del arreglo "hebra_original" (A, G, T, C), se impriman en forma aleatoria hasta completar 80 elementos?; ya que el tamaño del arreglo es 80.
Gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No necesitas tener un *array* de 80 elementos. Simplemente con esto basta:

```c
char hebra_original[5] = {'A', 'G', 'T', 'C'};
```

> > cómo puedo hacer que los valores del arreglo "hebra_original" (A, G, T, C), se impriman en forma aleatoria hasta completar 80 elementos?

Ejecuta un bucle que haga 80 iteraciones y luego calculamos el índice del *array* de forma aleatoria de esta forma:

```c
rand() % 4
```

Código de ejemplo:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char hebra_original[5] = {'A', 'G', 'T', 'C'}; 
    
    for(int i = 0; i < 80; ++i)
        printf("%c\n", hebra_original[rand() % 4]);
    return 0;
}
```